# "Check out these companies" sidebar is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, sidebar, site-ads

I noticed that the recently added ***Check out these companies*** sidebar is broken.
Many times it lists a company and says that it has 1 or 2 open positions, and when you click to go to the company page the company has zero open positions.

Here is a screenshot of an example page with the issue:

[image: Check out these companies]

The company  [Confluence](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/confluence-technologies-inc) is listed as having 2 open jobs and actually has 0 open jobs.
The company [PowerInbox](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/powerinbox) is listed as having 1 open job and actually has 0 open jobs.

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: The amount of times that I have encountered this bug seems to indicate that caching is unlikely the issue.

Comment: I don't see _Check out these companies_. I see _Looking for a job?_ Is that the same thing? Does it have to do with my profile settings?

Comment: @Abra Stackoverflow appears to display different sidebars to different users at different times based on some sort of algorithm. Looking for a job is a different type of sidebar as far as I know.

Comment: If you block it, all these problems go away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this.

The problem was that the jobs that are shown in the company page are filtered based on your location, however the number of open jobs displayed in the ad weren't.

We updated the open job count in the ad to match what you see in the company page. The update was deployed a few minutes ago. Please let us know if you keep seeing this behavior.

Comment: Your saying that some company jobs are hidden based on the users geographical location?

Comment: Yes, the job listings that are surfaced to the user depend on the location targeting that employers use and the user's geographical location.

Comment: It appears to be working correctly now